# How to set relative include path in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, path

I wrote a library called MyLib with some Visual Studio projects in MyLib\Samples\, and the include files reside in MyLib\inc. In order to make these include files accessible in the projects, I need to add their path in the project properties.

I want to use a relative path, so that I don't need to change the properties each time I move the whole library folder to other places. But what does the relative path look like? For example, one of the project path is: ...\MyLib\Samples\proj1, how do I represent the ...\MyLib\inc relative to the project path?

Comment: This may be outdated but you could create a .bat file that defined a subst commands for mappings. For Example S:\Sources maps to the folder C:\xxx\xxx\Sources folder on a given system. Not sure it will work in your solution. But all you references could make use of s:\Sources regardless of environment.

Comment: Yeah, this is such a basic feature of build systems, and MSVS doesn't seem to have a good method.  I hope someone finds this and gives us a decent answer!

Answer (score 9):

Use [the `$(SolutionDir)` or `$(ProjectDir)` MSBuild properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) to root the paths.  These are replaced at build-time with the directory in which the Solution and Project are located, respectively.

Comment: This doesn't really work for the question (as I understand it).  The use case is when a project consumes a library, and you want the client of the library to inherit include paths from the library.  The $(SolutionDir) and $(ProjectDir) will be paths relative to the client of the library, not the library.

Comment: Best practice here is to not use relative paths for this situation. I have worked with code bases in the past that used relative paths, and later the introduction of exporting the relative path projects as libs for external use caused absolute hell - Flooded additional include property to accommodate for every projects $(ProjectDir) field. Not nice.

Comment: Looking so long for this. So simple!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is *custom properties* for your project.

Visual Studio has support for defining [custom properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx#bkmkPropertySheets) which you can subsequently use in macro expansions in your include path, for example.

Here's an example of how it looks like:
[image]